# Time Duration to Numeric Minutes using Python Library or Regex

Tags: python, regex, time

I have a free form time duration strings containing hour and minute values one of then could be optional

```
1 hour
12 hours 3 mins
47 mins
10 hours
1 min
```

I have to convert them to number of minutes. First searched for Python library which converts times and duration but the string format does not allow to use such approach

Then I tried with regex to extract the number groups:

```
re.search("(\d+)?.*(\d+\w)", string).group(1)
re.search("(\d+)?.*(\d+\w)", string).group(2)
```

which worked for most cases when hour and minute values are present or when only the minute value is present (since I made the first group optional) This regex fails when the hour is single digit (1 hour).
Also because I am extracting only digits groups without the descriptive text (hour(s) and/or min(s) the calculation is wrong when there is only the hour value (with two digits) - like 10 hours and it wrongly is extracted as the 2nd group as minutes.

Comment: You can extract time data from a string using `datetime.strptime()` from python library [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with the following regex:

```
import re
s = '''1 hour
12 hours 3 mins
47 mins
10 hours
1 min'''
for h, m in re.findall(r'(?=\d+ *hours?| *\d+ *min(?:ute)?s?)(?:(\d+) *hours?)?(?: *(\d+) *min(?:ute)?s?\b)?', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
    print(int(h or 0) * 60 + int(m or 0))
```

This outputs:

```
60
723
47
600
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this simple snippet that parses all your cases. Ask if you had any problem.

Output:

```
1 hour -> 1:00:00
12 hours 3 mins -> 12:03:00
47 mins -> 0:47:00
10 hours -> 10:00:00
1 min -> 0:01:00
random text -> 0:00:00
```

Code:

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta


number_word_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+) (\w+)')


def parse_fuzzy_duration(s):
    ret = timedelta(0)

    for number, word in number_word_regex.findall(s):
        number = int(number)

        if word in ['minute', 'min', 'minutes', 'mins']:
            ret += timedelta(minutes=number)
        elif word in ['hour', 'hours']:
            ret += timedelta(hours=number)

    return ret


for s in ['1 hour', '12 hours 3 mins', '47 mins', '10 hours', '1 min', 'random text']:
    print(s, '->', parse_fuzzy_duration(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **[dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)** and Regex

**Demo:**

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import re

s = """1 hour
12 hours 3 mins
47 mins
10 hours
1 min"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    print(dparser.parse(re.sub(r"(mins?)", "minutes", line), fuzzy=True).strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
01:00:00
12:03:00
00:47:00
10:00:00
00:01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers is fine, another way to do this with regex (if you really want to):

```
match = re.match(
    r'((?P<hours>\d+) hours?)? ?((?P<mins>\d+) mins?)?',
    '12 hours 3 mins'
)

match.groupdicts()
```

This way it *may* make more sense you you (this is the main problem with a lot of regex engineering. I'd suggest to try out any regex you choose at some resource like https://regex101.com/ to have some testing and description.

Comment: blhsing's answer was more fool proof engineered so even if I put arbitrary number of white-spaces between the number and the hour/min  pattern it selects the digits. However your's was shorter and thus easier to understand so I was able to change it to the same behavior   : `((?P<hours>\d+) *hours?)? ?((?P<mins>\d+) *mins?)?` - thanks